# If value is null get the one from before

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get last row's value if current value is null?

I tried using LAG, but it returns null after second row.

```
SELECT timestamp, min, lag(min) over (order by id asc) as lag
from table
```

[image]

Comment: This is expected for LAG. It looks at the previous row, not the previous value, so if the previous row's value is NULL that's what you'll see.

Comment: I think you would need the `LAG(min) IGNORE NULLS` option but the current version of MySQL doesn't support that option (cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, you can try to `SUM` window function make a group then use `max`/`min` window function.

```
SELECT `timestamp`, 
     `min`,
      CASE WHEN `min` IS NULL THEN MAX(`min`) OVER(PARTITION BY grp order by id asc)  END
FROM (
    SELECT `timestamp`, 
           `min`, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN `min` IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(order by id asc) grp
    from `table`
) t1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba32a0e27c9b33adb4737df43aeb1ddb)

Comment: max(min) doesn't help, I might have a lower number.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4877ca34f22fe5f7a8e11bcf139c3b49

Comment: @flowstacker I see, I edited my answer you can try that